# TTL (TCP/IP time to live) changing in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-tweak

I want to increase packages time to live in Ubuntu.

What exactly I want to do: photos and XMLs in browser (Chrome) are downloading for about a minute. I don't want the connection to be broken in 20 seconds, but, for example 120 seconds.

Comment: TTL is the amount of routers your packages will go through. E.g. if it is 64, the first router will decrease it to 63, the second to 62 and so on. If the datagram reaches a TTL 0 it gets dropped, this is a security measure against loops in the internet. Your TTL value is certainly not responsible for your slow internet connection, so changing it will have no effect.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [here](http://forum.soft32.com/linux/change-TTL-Linux-ftopict440551.html), I see that you need to write to this file: `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_default_ttl`.

However, I'm not really sure that that will fix your problem.

Comment: Even after doing that TTL is still 64. Are we sure that it is not hardcoded somewhere?